# trying to assign callback variable with SDL for audio

Tags: c++, audio, sdl

When I try to assign the callback variable in the AudioSpec structure, the compiler doesn't like it when I'm trying to assign a type "void function" to a type SDL_AudioCallback.

```
void mainEngineCW4::myAudioCallback(void* userdata, Uint8* stream, int Glen) {

AudioData* audio = (AudioData*)userdata;

if (audio->length == 0)
    return;

Uint32 length = (Uint32)len;
length = (length > audio->length ? audio->length : length); // if length is more than the audio length, then set length to be the audio.length, if not, set it to be the length passed to the function

SDL_memcpy(stream, audio->position, length);

audio->position += length;
audio->length -= length; }

void mainEngineCW4::playAudio() // this function is for loading an audio device, and playing the audio through that device {

AudioData audio;
audio.position = wavStart;
audio.length = wavLength;

wavSpec.callback = mainEngineCW4::myAudioCallback;
wavSpec.userdata = &audio;

audioDevice = SDL_OpenAudioDevice(NULL, 0, &wavSpec, NULL, SDL_AUDIO_ALLOW_ANY_CHANGE);
if (audioDevice == 0)
{
    std::cerr << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    return;
}

SDL_PauseAudioDevice(audioDevice, 0); // mildly confused by why they decided to call the function for starting to play audio for "PauseAudioDevice" but yeah. this plays audio. }
```

I've split the responsibilities of the controlling audio into three functions, loadAudio, startAudio and endAudio. I've assigned the variables needed for the audio in the .h file, so it is accessible for all the functions in the class.

[image: this is the error]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SDL callback signature is a stand-alone function of type `void (*)(void* userdata, Uint8* stream, int len)`.

Your callback signature is close but not quite a match: `void (mainEngineCW4::*)(void* userdata, Uint8* stream, int len)`.

The main difference is that it is a *member* function, which is part of its type. In short, that type -- member function -- implies that you must call it with an instance of a class, which becomes the `this` pointer, e.g., `myEngine->myAudioCallback( ... )`. Stand-alone functions do not have a `this` pointer and so would be called like `standAloneAudioCallback( ... )`.

One way to resolve this is to make `myAudioCallback` a *static* member function. Another way is to make is a non-member (aka, stand-alone) function.

In either case, if you need to access (non-static) member data for the `mainEngineCW4` class that it is currently a part of, you will need to get access to it, usually by a static or global variable or by using the `userdata` param to store the class instance. I'd need to see a little more of your program to demonstrate it precisely.

---

*Update responding to your comments*:

There are a couple ways you could do this. Probably what you want is to set the `userdata` in your audio spec to your instance of the engine class and pass in a static (or standalone) callback that uses that pointer to call the member function:

```cpp
class mainEngineCW4 
{
    struct AudioData { /* ... */ };

    // Private static member function, but could be a stand-alone function
    static void myStaticAudioCallback( void* const userData, Uint8* const stream, const int len )
    {
        const auto myEngine = reinterpret_cast<mainEngineCW4*>( userData );
        myEngine->myAudioCallback( stream, len );
    }

    void myAudioCallback( const Uint8* const stream, const int len )
    {
        // ... Process stream using AudioData struct or whatever
    }

public:
    void playAudio()
    {
        auto audioSpec = SDL_AudioSpec{};
        // ... set the freq and format and what not in the audio spec
        audioSpec.callback = &myStaticAudioCallback;
        audioSpec.userdata = this;

        const auto audioDevice = SDL_OpenAudioDevice( NULL, 0, &audioSpec, NULL, SDL_AUDIO_ALLOW_ANY_CHANGE);
        // ...
    }
};
```

I've written it here all in the class definition for concision, but you can split it out to the `.h`/`.cpp` if you want. I've also added some `const`'s, which are good practice, and I followed "[Almost Always Auto](https://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/)" style.

Comment: I essentially need to make audiocallback to not be a member of my class, instead I need to make it a function that doesn't translate to a member of said class?

While I get the concept, I don't fully understand how I'm supposed to declare a function outside of my mainEngineCW4 class, I've been trying a bit of different things, like declaring the function outside of the mainEngineCW4 class, and instead declaring it outside of the class in its entirety.
You said you would need to see more of my program to demonstrate it. What more do you need to see to assist more? If you don't mind, that is

Comment: im still somewhat new to C++, so apologies for the lack of information or lack of understanding.
Thank you so much for the response, nevertheless.

Comment: I've updated the answer to attempt to answer your questions.

Comment: thanks for the update, i answered myself below to show what I've done to fix the error.
thank you incredibly much, this made me understand how the hierarchy works i C++ better than i did before.
I am running into an additional error if you don't mind helping me once again?

Comment: I'm not sure what the new error you're seeing is. If it's unrelated, perhaps ask a new question? If it's related, you can try to elaborate here or edit your question to add some new details. In any case, if you implement it as a static member function calling a member function as I have done in this answer, you should have access to all members of the class such as your `AudioData` struct from within `myAudioCallback()`.

Comment: will make a new question, thanks for tall the help, kind sir.
Hope you have a wonderful day!

Answer (score 0):

as metal replied earlier, the mistake is that i tried to define myAudioCallback in my mainEngineCW4 class.

```
class mainEngineCW4
{
public:
void myAudioCallback();
}
```

instead, declare it outside the class.

the error i ran into at first while doing this, was not being able to access the struct AudioData, but that was also defined in the class. simply define both outside of the class.

```
class mainEngineCW4
{}
struct AudioData {
Uint8* position;
Uint32 length;};
void myAudioCallback(void* userdata, Uint8* stream, int len);
```